# Vim is black and white in 256 color terminal

Tags: vim

In terminal.
I use 256-color terminal:

```
-->tput colors
256
```

I see colorized termial (PS1 and directory list) in Putty.

In Vim.
I set colorscheme to what I need:

```
:color
sweyla891274
```

I set t_Co to 256:

```
set t_Co
 t_Co=256
```

I see correct syntax:

```
set syntax
 syntax=cpp
```

Finally, I see colorized according to colorscheme text when I print in Vim :highlight.
Nevertheless my Vim is black and white.
Why????

Below is screenshot for :highlight

[image: result of :highlight]

Comment: A screenshot and `~/.vimrc` contents would be helpful. You do have `:syntax on`, right?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat: yes, syntax is on.  
Don't know how to submit .vimrc here in appropriate way

Comment: You could post it e.g. on https://gist.github.com/ and link it from your question.

Comment: Does `:syn list` show you the `cpp...` syntax groups (in the C++ buffer)?

Comment: @IngoKarkat: in response to `:syn list` it says `No Syntax items defined for this buffer`. It seems the Vim installation is broken. But it was installed (and reinstalled just now) without any problem using command `sudo zypper install vim`

Comment: @IngoKarkat: I eliminated .vimrc at all and started without it with the same result. BTW, that .vimrc I successfully usedon many many other machines without any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the syntax definitions for the `cpp` filetype. Check the output of `:scriptnames`, it shows all sourced scripts, and should contain `syntax/cpp.vim` from your *runtime path*. Also, check `:set runtimepath?`, and whether everything is properly installed.

Comment: by some reason Vim installation does contain syntax/syntax.vim file only and no any language files. I'm sure it is root of cause. OpenSUSe's Zypper installs Vim improperly.

Comment: Yes. I downloaded Vim from vim.org, make and installed manually. Now it is colorized. Thankx for your cooperation.